# Who/What am I? A riddle poem of satire

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

I'm gigantic and pedantic,

I come in many parts.

Some see me as rigorous,

but I'm unspokenly ridiculous.

I like to guess and play,

when it's my turn to say.

I'm power-law distributed,

not all at once refuted.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

> The Puzzling Stack Exchange

I'm gigantic

> There are over 26,000 questions, not to mention all the answers

and pedantic,

> If you are new to the site, it can feel a bit pedantic with all the rules/guidelines/conventions regarding how/when to post/comment. (But you'll figure it out with time).
>  Users are always happy to discuss content, no matter how inconsequential. [Is it green or yellow? Yes, okay, it's green-yellow. But I'm too lazy to fix it! : ) (all in good fun, I was wondering if someone would notice.)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120781/valence-levels?noredirect=1#comment336976_120781)

I come in many parts.

> There's a chat room, a main board, a meta forum, tags page, users page, etcetera...

Some see me as rigorous,

> Some might desire this to be a master repository of "all" distinct puzzles and their solutions, in a "well" organized (e.g. tags, etc.) manner. Define "all" and "well" however you like. After all, this is satire.

but I'm unspokenly ridiculous.

> And yet... why are we even reading this? In the end, when all is said and done, was our time well spent, scouring lists of words for element names, or trying to find fragments of morse code in pixel art? I suppose it could be a bit ridiculous...  but we had fun!

I like to guess and play,

> That's the main activity going on here...

when it's my turn to say.

> But don't answer if someone else already did! And don't comment just to say hi! And...  : )

I'm power-law distributed,

> A small number of [users](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) make up the bulk of the activity, and it follows the power law from there.

not all at once refuted.

> Alas, there are plenty of unanswered puzzles which, no matter how curious you are to see the solution, seem to linger in [unanswered](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/unanswered) state forever...

What am I?

> You are, in a satirical (and hopefully in good fun) way, **The Puzzling Stack Exchange**!

Answer (score 3):

I guess the answer *probably* is -

> [Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability)

I'm gigantic and pedantic,

> The subject of probability is of-course gigantic and well, full of rules....

I come in many parts.

> Part as in sample spaces....

Some see me as rigorous,

> When detailed....

but I'm unspokenly ridiculous.

> It is in-fact believed to be [ridiculous](https://www.reddit.com/r/unpopularopinion/comments/ge6kxc/probability_is_a_stupid_concept_and_should_never/)...

I like to guess and play,
when it's my turn to say.

> It's use in guessing and betting in various sports/games....

I'm power-law distributed,

> Could be referring to [Power-law probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Power-law_probability_distributions)....

not all at once refuted.

> You can't completely reject the outcomes of it....

Comment: Good one. I don't quite get the title though.