# Valence Levels?

Tags: word, knowledge, visual, chemistry

Each yellow and orange (barred to distinguish) dot gets a letter.
The center green dot does not get a letter.
The final answer is a relevant word, once you unscramble it.

[image: Valence Levels]

Comment: yellow? looks like green ...

Comment: @AcK It does look a tad chartreuse, but I would still call it yellow. Especially as compared to the nucleus

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The final answer is:

> **ELECTRON**

We know that we need to enter letters into each circle (except the green one) in this diagram which resembles very much a diagram of [electron shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell):

[image: Electron shells for Uranium, as an example]

So what should we try to enter here? Well, of note here is that we appear to have **12 words** spelled out from the centre to the outermost edge, sharing letters with neighbouring words where required. And since we have a chemistry theme, it isn't too far to leap (if you have the knowledge) to attempting to fit...

> ...the names of 12 elements that begin with the same letter. And there's only one letter which starts the name of 12 chemical elements: **C**. Those elements being CADMIUM, CAESIUM, CALCIUM, CALIFORNIUM, CARBON, CERIUM, CHLORINE, CHROMIUM, COBALT, COPERNICIUM, COPPER, and CURIUM.
>
>  Counting up the number of letters in these and the number of letters in the words radiating out from the centre of the diagram, I realised this was a perfect match, as long as 'CAESIUM' was spelled with the 'A' that is often omitted in US English.

If we do this, we end up with the resulting filled diagram:

> [image: Completed diagram]
>
>  My order of completion:
>
>  1. CAESIUM (only 7 letter word using the pre-filled 'E' in the third position - also confirmed the need for using the 'AE' variant spelling).
>
>  2. CALCIUM/CALIFORNIUM due to the shared first 3 letters.
>
>  3. CADMIUM - the only remaining 7-letter element on the list.
>
>  4. COPPER/COPERNICUM (the other long word on the list).
>
>  5. COBALT, using the 'CO' beginning.
>
>  6. CERIUM/CURIUM - two words differing by a single letter.
>
>  7. CARBON - the remaining 6-letter element.
>
>  8. CHROMIUM/CHLORINE, positioned so that 'CHLORINE' shared the 5th-position 'R' with 'COPERNICUM'.

Finally, look at the 8 letters in orange. These anagram to:

> **ELECTRON**, a very appropriate word given the theme of the puzzle.

Comment: Great work! I updated with the missing cell, glad it didn't hang you up.

Comment: Ahh! I tried going from the other direction for a bit and then gave up -_-

Comment: Thanks @Amoz - fixed to match :)